# Where can I retrieve a complete history of macro economic data annoucements?

Tags: macroeconomics, financial-economics, central-banking, federal-reserve, data

I'd like to get the complete ( well at least the last 20 years) history of economic data announcement calendar firstly for US and secondly for G5 countries.

I have found many websites that propose the real time calendar so they yield the upcoming economic announcement dates but do not keep the previous announcement date (or at max the previous year)

For instance:

https://tradingeconomics.com/calendar

or https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/calendars/nationalecon_cal.html

or https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/economic/

Having the figures of the economic indicators would be a plus.

Any clues guys?

Thanks

Comment: Your second link has historical dates: for example for January 2020 they are at https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/calendars/i-jan20.html and you could construct a script to capture these for every month over the last five years

Comment: actually I have tried and i can only go back to January 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Federal Reserve Economic Data (FRED) system may have some of the data you are seeking. For example the links below may be helpful directly or indirectly to inform your further search efforts.

FRED  recent release calendar:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/releases/calendar

FRED web services release dates:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/fred/releases_dates.html